# Convert month and year into normal date format in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

```
 <DatePicker onChange={this.dateSelect} value={this.state.dateselected} format={"MM/YYYY"} mode="month" picker="month" disabledDate={(current) => {
                    return moment().add(-4, 'month') >= current;
                }} />
```

date picker didn't shows the value on edit.. We get date as MM/YYYY format from backend. How to display?

Comment: Please include the code of `DatePicker` in the question

Comment: antd datepicker I used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the date using moment when passing the `value` prop, as:

```
 <DatePicker
      value={moment(this.state.dateselected, "YYYY/MM")}
      onChange={onChange}
      format={"YYYY/MM"}
      picker="month"
      disabledDate={(current) => {
        return moment().add(-4, "month") >= current;
      }}
    />
```

[View demo on codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-antd-4-18-9-forked-xl8yh3?file=/index.js:309-540)

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the date components and pass them into the [Date() constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date).

```js
const [month, year] = "01/2022".split("/");
const date = new Date(parseInt(year), parseInt(month) - 1);
console.log(date.toString());
// 'Sat Jan 01 2022 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can convert it via [dateformat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dateformat) library for example:

```
1. npm install dateformat
2. import dateFormat from 'dateformat';
3. dateFormat("2022-03-7T08:59:00.000Z", "mmmm dS, yyyy") to get March 7th, 2022
or dateFormat("2022-03-7T08:59:00.000Z", "dddd, mmmm dS, yyyy") to get Tuesday, March 7th, 2022.
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/dateformat

Answer (score 0):

I think it gives an error is because `new Date()` function only accepts a specific format `YYYY-MM-DD` or `YYYY/MM/DD` so if your `Date` is not in that format then it will give you an error.

So what you can do is convert your `date` into a `string` and pass `date`, `month`, `year` as arguments. You can use the below code for that.

```
function convertFromStringToDate(responseDate) {
    let dateComponents = responseDate.split('T');
    let datePieces = dateComponents[0].split("-");
    let timePieces = dateComponents[1].split(":");
    return(new Date(datePieces[2], (datePieces[1] - 1), datePieces[0],
                         timePieces[0], timePieces[1], timePieces[2]))
}

convertFromStringToDate("21-03-2020T11:20:30")
```